# javascript function show / hide multiple divs with first div visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to make the first target div always be visible when the page loads whilst the others become visible as the user selects the option. Currently they are all hidden as the page is loaded and only become visible once the buttons are clicked.

## JS

```
 $('.targetDiv').hide();
 $('.show').click(function () {
 $('.targetDiv').hide();
 $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
 });
```

## HTML

```
<div class="buttons">
 <a  class="show" target="1">Option 1</a>
 <a  class="show" target="2">Option 2</a>
 <a  class="show" target="3">Option 3</a>
 <a  class="show" target="4">Option 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 4</div>
```

Comment: `$('#div1').show();`

Comment: Remove `class="targetDiv" ` from first div and use `$('#div1').show();`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$('.targetDiv:not(#div1)').hide()` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/729/)

```js
$('.targetDiv:not(#div1)').hide();
$('.show').click(function() {
  $('.targetDiv').hide();
  $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use `:gt(0)`:-

> **:gt()** Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

```
$('.targetDiv:gt(0)').hide();
```

**Note:**

> **[target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target)**
>
> This attribute specifies where to display the linked resource. (_self,
>   _blank, _parent, _top)
>
> Use this attribute only if the href attribute is present.

Therefore I would recommend using **data**:-

```
<a class="show" data-target="1">Option 1</a>
```

and get the value using:-

```
$(this).data('target')
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `.show()` on the first div after hiding the others:

```
$('.targetDiv').hide();
$('#div1').show();

$('.show').click(function () {
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```

Comment: Why do you hide it in the first place? Shouldn't you just use `:not()`?

Comment: ...could have sworn i did that...must be loosing my mind...lack of sleep! Thanks!

Comment: @JacobGray use which ever you want. Both valid options.

Comment: @Turnip IMHO, the isn't the best way, as you are creating an unnecessary object

Comment: I refer you to my last comment. If you are really concerned about that level of micro-optimisation, don't use this. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(".targetDiv").not(':first').hide();
   $('.show').click(function () {
   $('.targetDiv').hide();
   $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can simply hide div by css in HTML [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jitendratiwari/2vbL7sa9/1/)

**HTML**

```
   <div class="buttons">
       <a  class="show" target="1">Option 1</a>
       <a  class="show" target="2">Option 2</a>
       <a  class="show" target="3">Option 3</a>
       <a  class="show" target="4">Option 4</a>
   </div>

   <div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 1</div>
   <div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum 2</div>
   <div id="div3" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum 3</div>
   <div id="div4" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum 4</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 //$('.targetDiv').hide();
$('.show').click(function () {
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```